# Equivalent for predict_proba in statsmodels Logistic Regression in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I created Logisitc Regression Model in statsmodels in Python like below:

```
model = sm.Logit(y_train, X_train[selected_features]).fit(disp = 0)
```

and then I need to calculate probabilities, (NOT prediction model.predict) but probabilities, same like `predict_proba` in sklearn. But whne I try to use `predict_proba` in statsmodels like below:

```
y_proba_1 = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
```

I have error: `AttributeError: 'LogitResults' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'`

Is there some equivalent for `predict_proba` from sklearn in statsmodels in Python ?

I need to hae equivalent for below lines which works in sklearn but does not wokrs in statsmodels:

```
y_proba_0 = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,0]
y_proba_1 = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
```

Comment: The LogitResults object from statsmodels does not have a `predict_proba`. you can use `predict` instead.
`y_proba_1 = model.predict(X_test)`
If I am not sure if I get your question well but I guess this is what you need. 
`y_proba_0 = 1 - y_proba_1`

Comment: Phoenix, your are genius, why I didn't come up with it myself